# Translating the language in a textbox on submit click

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

I am beginner with the Zend Framework. I have a simple form that contains a text box and a submit button. I want to translate the language in that text box when I click on submit, and also I want to print the translated language.

Comment: http://techie.ayyappadas.com/how-do-use-poeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it..the helpful reference is given bellow..

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/GoogleTranslator.aspx
```